# Full screen YouTube still shows Dock and Menu Bar

Tags: macos, fullscreen, youtube

Whenever I bring a video to fullscreen on YouTube (on Chrome or Safari), the video will go to fullscreen but the dock and menu bar remain visible, covering the top and bottom parts of the video. They used to be hidden when I went to fullscreen, so I don't know what happened. How do I fix this?

Comment: Go to the Apple menu, and from the Dock submenu select "Turn Hiding On".

Comment: I'd like the Dock to only hide when I'm in fullscreen mode though. Also that doesn't fix the menu bar issue.

Comment: Like I said, this used to be what happened before when going full screen, but it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem anymore, for some reason. The only thing I can think of that I did that could have resolved this is that I unplugged and replugged one of my monitors. So if you have a Mac mini like me, or a Mac Pro, you might want to try that.

Comment: i saw similar behavior on archive.org.  i believe it was the difference between flash and some other delivery method (html 5?).  not sure how to test this immediately.

Comment: Could you post some info about your system (version of safari and os x)

Comment: I have seen similar issues related to how I setup Spaces when using Firefox. This may also be related to using multiple displays. Do you have Multiple Displays? Check the setting of `System Preferences -> Mission Control -> Displays of separate Spaces`. Try chaining it even if you don't have multiple displays. This will require a logout.

Comment: Are you using a secondary monitor? This is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396980

Answer (score 104):

If none of that works, open Terminal and enter `killall Dock`.

Comment: Good solution! Got a 1 up

Comment: This is the best solution I've found

Comment: Did not work for me.. chrome bookmarkbar still visible :/

Comment: This worked for me!  But what did that do?

Comment: @LampShade: This force kills the process, like how you kill from Activity Monitor. Since, this is a crucial part of OS, iOS will restart it. Think of doing a reset to a good state(from buggy one).

Comment: So it's most likely a bug then, that's what I was getting at :-)

Comment: Awesome. How to unkill/reverse it, please?

Comment: @chikitin It will automatically respawn.

Answer (score 16):

I have this same problem with YouTube, Netflix, mPlayerX and VLC, where the Dock stays visible (on-top) after making the video go full screen.

This problem can be fixed by going into System Preferences...Mission Control and turning off the option "Displays have separate spaces."  You have to logout after making this change.

[image: Turn off displays have separate spaces]

Comment: This is wrong answer! What if I need separate spaces in my displays?

Comment: You're missing the point....we all agree that it should work correctly and this should not be necessary.  If you do this temporarily, it will work.  Imagine my frustration when I first had this issue and had no solution at all...it just didn't work and there were no work-arounds.

Answer (score 3):

If you make the browser fullscreen before making the video fullscreen, this problem should disappear.

Comment: I made browser go fullscreen and then back to normal state. After doing this, dock disappeared when video goes fullscreen. Thanks!

Comment: it's a workaround, but it's the only that works. even in 2022 on Moneterey this is the only way i've seen osx actually work "correctly". separate monitors will keep the menu bar when a browser video is full screen _only if_ the green-button full screen is clicked on the browser window first

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I find it. This has to do with multiple monitors and mirroring (I connect my tv on the mac). Turn "Display mirroring" to off. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

First switch Chrome window mode to full screen mode by pressing the green dot on the top left side of the view:

[image: chrome full screen mode green dot]

After that menu bar should be hidden so now enter full screen mode in youtube player:

[image: youtube full screen mode]

Enjoy your video on full screen without menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this is to change Dock positioning to somewhere else and putting it back to your preferred position.
You can do this under Dock & Menu Bar section of System Preferences.

[image: Dock Position System Preferences]

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to use `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="http://youtube.com"` to have it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered the source of this issue was the setting **Automatically show and hide the menu bar** being set to **Always**. By setting it to **In Full Screen Only**, the issue was resolved.

[image: Screenshot of the Control Centre settings for 'Menu Bar Only' showing the 'Automatically hide and show the menu bar' option set to 'In Full Screen Only']